# Why is XStream ignoring @XmlTransient?

Tags: jaxb, xstream

Does XStream handle JAXB @XmlTransient attributes by default?  XStream seems to be ignoring the @XmlTransient attribute & serializing the field anyway.

In the sample code below.  ExampleClass2 is getting serialized even though I don't want it to be.  Further details are that these classes are being populated by OpenJPA.

**XStream Code**

```
 XStream       _x0   =null;
_x = XStreamImpl.getInstance();
_x.toXML(_object)
```

**Class I want to serialize**

```
@DataCache
@Entity
public class ExampleClass implements Serializable {

    private short defaultOption;

    private int primaryKey;

    private short orderId;

    @XmlTransient
    private ExampleClass2 _exampleClass2;

    @XmlTransient
    public ExampleClass2 getTblPpwsCommCfgCombo() {
        return _exampleClass2;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public void setExampleClass2(ExampleClass2 _exampleClass2) {
        this._exampleClass2 = _exampleClass2;
    }

    public short getDefaultOption() {
        return defaultOption;
    }
    public void setDefaultOption(short defaultOption) {
        this.defaultOption = defaultOption;
    }
    public short getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }
    public void setPrimaryKey(int primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }
    public short getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
    public void setOrderId(short orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @Transient annotation or transiet key word:

```
@Transient
private ExampleClass2 _exampleClass2;
```

~